# R - Values comming out "wrong" in table

Tags: r

I use the following:

```
     analysis <- matrix(c(median(avitM), mean(avitM), var(avitM), sd(avitM), median(logavitM), mean(logavitM), var(logavitM), sd(logavitM)),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)


     analysis <- matrix(c(sum(median(avitM)), mean(avitM), var(avitM), sd(avitM), median(logavitM), mean(logavitM), var(logavitM), sd(logavitM)),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)

colnames(analysis) <- c("Median","Gennemsnit","Stikproevevarians","Stikproevespredning")
rownames(analysis) <- c("avitM","logavitM")
analysis <- as.table(analysis)
analysis
```

To get the following values in a matrix:

```
    Median   Gennemsnit Stikproevevarians Stikproevespredning
avitM    1.782350e+03 1.958979e+03      8.294475e+05        9.107401e+02
logavitM 7.485688e+00 7.484993e+00      1.916541e-01        4.377832e-01
```

The values as you see are a bit weird. Is there any way to express them not with e but as whole numbers?

Answer (score 0):

`options(scipen = 1000)` allows you to change that.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the respond. Where should I put that?

Comment: options() control the global options of your current R session. So you can simply send it into your console.